# Is there a support for AdonisJS with Cassandra?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, nosql, adonis.js

AdonisJS is growing in its popularity as the most famous NodeJS framework. So wonder if there any package that supports Cassandra NoSQL DB at this point of time with lucid ORM or any other ORM. It's a decision-making time to choose the framework. So can any of you share thoughts on this or provide helpful links to understand the integration with Adonis. Adonis has got inspired by Laravel, and Laravel has supporting packages for Cassandra.

- https://github.com/sonvq/laravel-cassandra
- https://github.com/Fuitad/laravel-cassandra

Look forward in hearing similar package available for Adonis as well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just decided to make the move from Laravel to AdonisJS. PHP has its downsides. But, its nice to have a Laravel equivalent in NodeJS that saves me from having to navigate the mess that is the NodeJS Ecosystem.

Anyways, I have yet to find one. I know there is a MongoDB package for Adonis. But, as far as I know, there is no Cassandra package for Adonis as of yet.